# pyqt and weak/strong ref: how to proceed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

[edit]
It seems I solved the problem... In fact, I now do that:

```
class Gameboard(QGraphicsScene):
    def deletePawn(self, num):
        pawnToDelete = self.pawns.pop(num)  
        pawnToDelete.delete()

class Pawn(QGraphicsItem):  
    def delete(self):
        child.prepareGemotryChange()
        child.setParent(None)
        #idem for each child
        self.gameboard.removeItem(self)
        self.gameboard = None
```

[/edit]

What is the good way to implement references in a pyqt QGraphicsScene?

I made a class Gameboard which inherits QGraphicsScene, and this gameboard contains a variable number of pawns (wich inherit QGraphicsPolygonItem)

Pawns can be created or deleted dynamically, creation is ok but deletion sometimes crash...

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtOpenGL

class Gameboard(QGraphicsScene):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Gameboard, self).__init__()
      self.pawns = {}
      self.currentPawn = None

   def createSquares(self):
      #create the polygons of the squares and affect their coordinates x,y

   def createPawn(self):
      pawn = Pawn(self)
      num = len(self.pawns)
      self.pawns[num] = pawn
      self.addItem(self.pawns[num]) 

   def deletePawn(self, num):
      self.currentPawn = None
      self.pawns[num].beforeDelete()
      self.pawns[num].prepareGeometryChange()  
      self.removeItem(self.pawns[num])
      del self.pawns[num] 

   def selectPawn(self, pawn):
      #a pawn is selected, by click for example
      self.currentPawn = pawn

   def keyPressEvent(self, event):
      ekey = event.key()
      if ekey == Qt.Key_Delete and self.currentPawn != None:
          num = self.currentPawn.number
          self.deletePawn(num) 


class Pawn(QGraphicsItem):
   def __init__(self, gameboard):
      super(Pawn, self).__init__()
      self.gameboard = gameboard  
      self.number = 0
      self.pos = (-1,-1)  
      self.name = ""

   def create(self, x, y, num):
      #create a QGraphicsPolygonItem, a QGraphixPixmapItem and a QGraphicsTextItem which are child of the QGraphicsItem Pawn, and set position
      self.number = num 
      self.pos = (x,y)
      self.gameboard.squares[(x,y)].occupiedBy = self 

   def move(self, newPos):
      self.gameboard.squares[self.pos].occupiedBy = None
      self.pos = newPos
      self.gameboard.squares[self.pos].occupiedBy = None

   def beforeDelete(self):
      #a function I add trying to get rid of the crash
      self.gameboard = None
      self.graphicsPolygon.setParent = None
      self.graphicsPix.setParent = None
      self.text.setParent = None 

   def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super(Pawn, self).mousePressEvent(event)
    if event.button() == 1:
       self.gameboard.currentPawn = self  
       event.accept()

class Square(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
   def __init__(self, gameboard):
      self.coordinates = (x,y)
      self.occupiedBy = None
```

What is the proper way to proceed, should I use `deleteLater`? 
Or maybe something with the `weakref` lib?
Is it because of the variable `gameboard` in Pawn?

Comment: What do you mean with "crash"? You should not be able to crash Python with a script.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer. PyQt is a wrapper around a third-party C++ toolkit. It's pretty easy to crash the interpreter if you don't take care with references.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `prepareGeometryChange` call? Qt will pass ownership back to the caller after removing an item. If you delete an item that Qt has scheduled some kind of update for, a crash is quite likely.

Comment: @ekhumoro I know what Qt is. But again: PySide should take care of memory management and it should not be possible to crash the interpreter using a Python script. If it is "pretty easy" to do so (not in my experience), I'd consider that a bug in PySide.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer. In my experience of answering nearly a thousand questions in the pyqt/pyside tags, I can assure you that some people have no problem finding ways to crash the interpreter ;-) But this is certainly not due to any bugs in pyqt/pyside. Automatic tracking of object ownership is *never* going be 100% perfect. Or to put it another way: if it *was* made perfect, many Qt APIs couldn't be wrapped at all. So a certain amount of compromise is inevitable, meaning developers sometimes need to be aware of when and how objects get deleted, in order to prevent crashes or memory leaks.

Comment: @ekhumoro OK, I happily accept it as a fact that there *are* ways to crash the interpreter with PyQt and let's not further discuss whether this should be possible or not.  Getting back to the question, I wanted the OP to explain what he/she meant with "crash", hoping that maybe we would see an exception backtrace being confused with an interpreter crash.  But without further feedback, I doubt that this question can be answered.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your comments. When I say 'crash', it's a real crash, everything freezes, and 'python doesn't respond' (I'm not sure of how it displays in english)...etc  I use IDDLE to run my script, but the crash also happens when I launch it 'directly' (by the way, I work with windows). The real problem is that I don't have any error message, and that is ...disappointing, with python.

Comment: @ekhumoro I had this problem before I add 'prepareGeometryChange', and I add this line trying to fix it. I should precise that some functions (like 'space using') could refer to the the pawn directly... I also feel like the script crash less often since I add this line before to delete: "self.pawns[num].gameboard = None"  (I hope that I am clear, but english isn't my native language, so excuse-me if I am not...)

Comment: @olinox14. Please post a [complete, self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. It's impossible to help without that.

Comment: Sorry, I edited that, trying to make it the more accurate I could, but there are about 5000 lines of code, so... difficult to really reproduce the problem. I would be glad if you only have some advice or tutos about the good way to implement references between graphicals objects, or about the way of delete it properly.

Comment: My mistake: deleteLater() isn't a function for QGraphicsitem but for QWidget.